# What do these marks indicate exactly on these tray icons when I run Python from a terminal?

Tags: terminal, python, iterm

I ran an Anaconda Python installation from iTerm using `python -i myscript.py`. It made a plot using Matplotlib. After I closed the plot, the two icons remain.

Each has a **dot** under it, and a **little arrow** on the bottom left corner.

- When I type `exit()` at the python prompt the Python icon disappears and the iTerm icon remains unchanged.
- When I close iTerm the dot disappears, *but the arrow remains.*

Exactly what do these indicate? What is it exactly that these dots and arrows are trying to tell me?

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short arrow is indicating alias. Some like that are also there in my Applications folder for apps which are located in `~/Library` folder.

So I can guess that when first photo's original process is done, alias is still active. This happens to me while using OpenCV. `closewindow()` is hard to perform. I have to force quit it every time(it kills jupyter server too), or reuse the window.

Comment: Interesting, a temporary alias. Thanks!